# What is the behaviour of $Q^{-3}\sum_{Q<q\le 2Q} \varphi(q^2)$ as $Q\to\infty$?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Denote by $\varphi$ [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), and adopt [I. M. Vinogradov's ($\ll$) asymptotic notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#History_(Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau,_Hardy,_and_Vinogradov_notations)). Furthermore, let 
$$S(Q)=\sum_{Q<q\le 2Q}\varphi(q^2).$$

We have
$$S(Q)\ll \sum_{Q<q\le 2Q}q^2\ll \sum_{Q<q\le 2Q} Q^2\ll Q^3.$$
This implies that 
$$\limsup_{Q\to\infty} \frac{S(Q)}{Q^3}$$
is finite.

> To what number does the above $\limsup$ evaluate?

Similarly, we have
$$S(Q)\gg \sum_{Q<q\le 2Q}\frac{q^2}{\log\log q}\gg \sum_{Q<q\le 2Q} \frac{Q^2}{\log\log Q}\gg \frac{Q^3}{\log\log Q}.$$
The linear regression I ran on $S(Q)$ v. $Q^3$ over $1\le Q\le 1000$ [fits extremely well](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ifYFJAsJaLKEzlnpT0to6Ji6mX7ZqGNDINEPnWUH7AU/edit?usp=sharing). This makes me think that 
$$\liminf_{Q\to\infty} \frac{S(Q)}{Q^3}$$
is also worthy of consideration.

> To what does the above $\liminf$ evaluate?

Comment: Did you look at the pole at $s=3$ of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \varphi(n^2) n^{-s} = \prod_p(1+\sum_{k \ge 1}(p-1) p^{2k-1}p^{-sk})= \zeta(s-2) F(s)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$p_k(x)=\sum_{n=1}^x\varphi(x^k)$$ for $k=1,2$.

It is known that

$$p_1(x) = \frac{3}{\pi^2}x^2+o(x^2).$$

Thus, $$p_2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^xn\varphi(n)=xp_1(x)-\sum_{n=1}^{x-1}p_1(n)=\frac{3}{\pi^2}x^3+o(x^3)-\frac{1}{\pi^2}(x-1)^3+o((x-1)^3)=\frac{2}{\pi^2}x^3+o(x^3).$$

Now,

$$S(x)=p_2(2x)-p_2(x)=\frac{14}{\pi^2}x^3 +o(x^3).$$

So,

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{S(x)}{x^3}=\frac{14}{\pi^2}$$